# Get angular-directive-instance even though it´s not rendered

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

Im trying to get an angular directive instance even if it´s not rendered yet.

For example, I got an app-component and baz-directive. I want to get the directive instance even if it is not shown / rendered to the dom. Of course I could control functionality by input var but in my case it would be better / easier to access the instance and call some funtions. So it should behave something like a NgIf* not only via input var but via instance function call.

So my question how do I get the instance even it is not rendered or are there any other / better ways to handle such a situation?

```
import {Component, Directive, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({selector: '[baz]'})
export class BazDirective
{
    constructor(protected view: ViewContainerRef, protected template: TemplateRef<any>)
    {
    }

    renderNow()
    {
        this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: "app-root", templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
    @ViewChild(BazDirective) bar: BazDirective


    constructor()
    {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void
    {
        this.bar.renderNow();
    }
}
```

`<div #bar *baz>foo</div>`

Comment: Not displayed = not accessible.

Comment: That's just the question, because the directive exists otherwise it could not react to input var changes, I guess.

Comment: The component exists, The directive doesn't. It's removed from the dom, you can't access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, it depends what you mean by not rendered. Because not visible doesn't mean it is not rendered.

With a structural directive, like it seems to be in your example, you can access your directive. Here is a live example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y7h7gk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
It is not the case if your directive is trully not rendered (wrap in a *ngIf for example).

And in your example you should not use the template variable `#bar` on your html element, because you are targetting the BazDirective with your @ViewChild().

Hope it helps!

Comment: My mistake. Diffing your and my version, I noticed my version did not work because I did not include the directive within module-declarations. So a stupid fault, no special angular behavour. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the #bar var was a leftover from some testing.

Comment: No problem! Great you fix your issue!